# how to convert an Anonymous to typed list in repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use the repository pattern to interact with data and have a book list that want get book with some fields. I provide an IEnumerable method in data layer that return list of required fields:

```
public IEnumerable BookList()
{
   var res=base.GetAll().Select(x => new { ID=x.ID, Name=x.Name }).ToList();
   return res;
}
```

In the presentation layer I try to change type to `BookViewModel` with this:

```
var res = _teacherUow.Books.BookList().OfType<ViewModel.BookViewModel >().ToList();
```

but `res` is empty and when I try to cast it

```
var res = _teacherUow.Books.BookList().Cast<ViewModel.BookViewModel >();
```

I receive this exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type <>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String]
    to type ViewModel.BookViewModel

var res = _teacherUow.Books.BookList();
```

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String]]
```

but this dictionary requires a model item of type

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ViewModel.BookViewModel]
```

Comment: You need to manually *map* `Book` to `BookViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

in your presentation layer change your function to be like that:

```
 public IEnumerable<ViewModel.BookViewModel> BookList() 
{ 
    List<ViewModel.BookViewModel> res=base.GetAll().Select(x => new ViewModel.BookViewModel { 
                                ID=x.ID, 
                                Name=x.Name 
                              }).ToList(); 
return res; 
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this, keeping type anonymous?

Comment: in select remove "ViewModel.BookViewModel" and you will have an anonymous object type.

Comment: is there anyway to pass view model class back to sub layer to convert data in requested model format?

Comment: Since your BookList() Function return an IEnumerable List you can select the result as your Object:
 var res = _teacherUow.Books.BookList().Select(x => new ViewModel.BookViewModel { ID=x.ID, Name=x.Name }).ToList();

is that Answer your Question ?